# How to retrieve an array of images from a plist file which is shown in an imageview?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

How do I retrieve image data from plist and display to that data to an image view?

Comment: Are you saying you have the name of a bunch of images in the plist file?

Comment: [what have you tried ?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: Are the images themselves in a plist or just references to images stored in the bundle?  You should not be storing the image data in the plist.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)getImages {

    // Look in Documents for an existing plist file
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(
                                                         NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    myPlistPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent: 
                   [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@.plist", plistName] ];
    [myPlistPath retain];

    // If it's not there, copy it from the bundle
    NSFileManager *fileManger = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    if ( ![fileManger fileExistsAtPath:myPlistPath] ) {
        NSString *pathToSettingsInBundle = [[NSBundle mainBundle] 
                                            pathForResource:plistName ofType:@"plist"];
    }

    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(
                                                         NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectoryPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *path = [documentsDirectoryPath 
                      stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"myApp.plist"];
    NSMutableDictionary *plist = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile: path];

    NSArray *imageArray = [plist objectForKey:@"imageArray"];

    for (NSString *imageString in imageArray) {
        DLog(@"Image Name: %@", imageString);
    }

}
```

Get plist code from [www.iphoneexamples.com](http://iphoneexamples.com)